# Mongoose duplicates with the schema key unique

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to make the key project unique across that collection but i cant getting this working, i found similar problem here.

task.js

```
function make(Schema, mongoose) {

    var Tasks = new Schema({
        project: { type: String, index: { unique: true, dropDups: true }},
        description: String
    });

    mongoose.model('Task', Tasks);
}
module.exports.make = make;
```

test.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rss');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

require('./task.js').make(Schema, mongoose);
var Task = mongoose.model('Task');
var newTask = new Task({
    project: 'Starting new project'
  , description: 'New project in node'
});
newTask.save(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log('Error on saving');
});

mongoose.disconnect();
```

When i run the app with node test.js, still creates duplicates.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: rss
> db.tasks.find()
> db.tasks.find()
{ "project" : "Starting new project", "description" : "New project in node", "_id" : ObjectId("4f21aaa3d48d4e1533000001") }
{ "project" : "Starting new project", "description" : "New project in node", "_id" : ObjectId("4f21aaa4d9a8921a33000001") }
{ "project" : "Starting new project", "description" : "New project in node", "_id" : ObjectId("4f21aaa57ebeea1f33000001") }
```

// Edit still same problem, here's what i tried to do
delete the db.tasks.drop() collection
restart mongo sudo stop mongodb and start mongodb, ran the program again and still same problem, how does it allow duplicate data on index?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Schema object you're passing may not work correctly because you are nesting 'unique' attribute into 'index' attribute, try something like this (it works as intended) :

```
User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    firstName:  {
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    address: String,
    phone: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },
    password:  {
        type:String,
        required: true,
        set: Data.prototype.saltySha1 // some function called before saving the data
    },
    role: String
},{strict: true}));
```

Or more specifically for your example :

```
var Tasks = new Schema({
    project: { 
        type: String, 
        unique: true,
        index: true
    },
    description: String
});
```

Note : I don't know what you're trying to do with the "dropDups" parameter, it doesn't seems to be in the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Comment: dropDups is from mongodb-native

Comment: dropDups is deprecated from version 2.6 https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#drop-duplicates

Comment: As per docs: specifying `index: true` is optional if you do `unique: true`

Comment: @Lukas I exactly quoted from a comment in an example from the official docs. Here's the section https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options you can see the comment in the example of the section (scroll down a little bit under 'indexes' part).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

function make(Schema, mongoose) {


  var Tasks = new Schema({
    project: {
      type: String,
      index: {
        unique: true,
        dropDups: true
      }
    },
    description: String
  });

  Tasks.plugin(uniqueValidator);

  mongoose.model('Task', Tasks);
}
module.exports.make = make;
```

use unique validator

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.