# mongoose - Enforce a certain field is unique across all Documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've done a fair bit of searching but can't seem to find a solid answer to this. 
Say I have a User model with a `username` field - and I want to ensure every `username` across all users is unique. Is there a way to enforce this through mongoose - such as a validator?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024176/mongoose-duplicates-with-the-schema-key-unique?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `username` field to be [`unique`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html) . This will ensure that `username` remains unique at the database level.

> unique: {Boolean} - Tells Mongoose to ensure a unique index is created for this path. The following are equivalent:

```
let Person = new Schema({ 
    name: name,
    unique: true
});
```